# Photo centering

Tags: html, css, photo

So long story short i have 4 photos, but when i make the screen a little smaller the 4th photo shifts down but its not in the padding box. any help?

```css
  body {
 background-image: url('background_repeat.jpg')
}
/*Start css for rest of page*/
.header{
text-align: center;
color: white
}
.photos{
 margin: 0px 30px 0px;
 padding: 30px;
 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
 text-overflow: clip;
 }
.media{
display: inline;
padding: 3px;
background-color: grey;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 10px;
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
}
.inline {
 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="body">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Photos</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="photos">
            <div class="inline">
            <video class="media" width="250" controls>
            <source src="New%20Edit.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <img class='media' src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSv8yf5AnclVcQwBtApNkfNlk5ZZKlxswqNylSgD7PhbACsjbXn">
            <img class='media' src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSv8yf5AnclVcQwBtApNkfNlk5ZZKlxswqNylSgD7PhbACsjbXn">
            <img class='media' src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSv8yf5AnclVcQwBtApNkfNlk5ZZKlxswqNylSgD7PhbACsjbXn">     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Am i just missing something or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display:inline` from your `.inline` **CSS** class, and you will see the fourth box centering the div on the next line. If you're looking forward to make your contents responsive, and well displayed in any view port, you have to use **Media Queries**, you can have comprehensive ideas about it reading this;

[Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

**And** the jsfiddle of the solution;

[Image Centered](https://jsfiddle.net/tn5c09a9/1/)